# Python socket recvfrom only shows first UDP packet sent

Tags: python, sockets, arduino, udp, buffer

I have a small Python server trying to receive UDP packets sent by an Arduino.
It's setup so that the Arduino constantly spams UDP packets, and the Python server keeps reading them.

The problem is that, even though I know the Arduino is sending several different messages, as it is advancing in its code, the Python program only seems to catch the first one.

Both devices are connected to the same network.

```
SHARED_UDP_PORT = 4210 # Port for communication
LOCAL_IP = "192.168.43.27" # Python machine local IP

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((LOCAL_IP,SHARED_UDP_PORT))



while True:
    message, address = recmsg(sock, message)
 

    if message == "Waiting to start": 
        reply = input(f"Input test header for {address} : ")

        sock.sendto(bytes(reply,"utf-8"), address) 
        message, address = recmsg(sock, message)
        sleep(3)
        pass
    if message == "Header received, ready to start test":
        sock.sendto(bytes("Ready to receive","utf-8"), address)
        message, address = recmsg(sock, message)
    if message == "Starting test":
        print("It's show time")
        message, address = recmsg(sock, message)
```

I've written a script 'recmsg', which tries to get around the problem of oversized buffers. I feel like the issue has to do with the buffer

```
def recmsg(sock, lastmessage):


    message, address = sock.recvfrom(256)
    size = len(message)
    message, address = sock.recvfrom(size)
    message = message.decode()
    print(size)
    print(f'{address} sent : \n {message}')
    if lastmessage == message:
        return(None, address)
    else:
        return(message, address)
```

When the code runs, the Python out put is always `('192.168.43.159', 4210) sent : Waiting to start`, as is expected, seeing as the Arduino is telling me `Sent package : Waiting to start` .

But even when I've sent a message to the Arduino, telling it to move on, the Python output stays the same, while the Arduino is sending `Sent package : Header received, ready to start test`. I'm still getting the same message and prompt, no matter how many times I send it.

I've tried setting the socket to non-blocking, which doesn't seem to change anything. The other answers I've seen address messages longer than the buffer size, but mine are short. I know the problem isn't with the Arduino, the Serial monitor is telling me it's working.

Is there some kind of message buffer than stays full with the first message, and I need to flush it before new ones can be read? The Arduino seems perfectly capable of parsing consecutive packets of varying length, but here I am.

Thanks.

Comment: You're calling `recvfrom()` twice, but never printing the first message.

Comment: @Barmar I understand that. But the problem isn't over one loop, it's over several iterations of the program. It's running in a while loop, and every print is the same.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in the first code block? If the `if` statements are supposed to be in the same loop as the  call to `recmsg` they need to be at the same indentation level.